# Rails semi-isolated engine: layout rendering heisenbug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, rendering, rails-engines

I have a weird bug in my engine that seems to show up randomly. Here's the problem : i have a `Blog` engine ; it has two main controllers, one for frontend and the other for backend. Both inherit from the parent application controllers ; the frontend one has its own layout, while the backend one uses the parent layout.

In development with webrick, the frontend fails to use its own layout when loading the app for the first time, **but works perfectly when rebooting webrick**. Then everything works fine, except sometimes when switching from backend to frontend.

The bug doesn't seem to show up on production with passenger.

I suspect two things :

- webrick is guilty
- there is a module load order issue

Could anyone have a clue about what causes this ?

Comment: I guess it's due to dev mode logic: almost everything is reloaded but not everything. try to run locally in prod environment

Comment: i guess it's possible, i'll try this when i have time. thanks !